# Responsive web design (RWD) is good for Admin (cPanel)?

Tags: responsive-design

Responsive web design (RWD) is good for admin side (control panel) of web design?

I have more entries and tables in my admin page. so RWD is good for admin development?

Also it is good for develop mobile application for admin forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know Responsive Web Design as 'Fluid and adaptive layouts with progressively enhancing features', then I think it's probably safe to say that yes, RWD is good for almost any web project. Be aware however, that building responsively is much more difficult and time consuming (read: expensive) and may not offer the necessary ROI that you need.

For example, consider that much backend software like cPanel and such are used by technically skilled people that understand how to resize their browser and work with less-than-polished software.

Also, when you think about cPanel, you must consider whether much of the utilities and functions it provides are efficient and useful in the mobile context - I doubt that sysadmins really want to do module installation or type large amounts of console code with an iPhone keyboard.

So when considering the merits of RWD for backend web software, be sure to weigh up your target audience, their skills and requirements, their equipment and what (and how) they will use the tools available to them to get things done.